# open and fill dropdownbox onload in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function myFunction()
    {
      alert("open the dropdownbox automatically onload");
      optionsSelect.focus();
      var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
      WshShell.SendKeys("%{DOWN}");
    //document.formName.elementName.focus();
    //document.F1.DD.focus();
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="myFunction()">
      <form>
       <select name="DD" id="DD" onMouseOver="this.size=20;" onload="this.size=20;">
        <option value="volvo">Audi</option>
        <option value="saab">Fiat</option>
        <option value="audi">Honda</option>
        <option value="fiat">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Saab</option>
        <option value="audi">Volvo</option>
       </select>
      </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

The best I could do so far is replace onload with onMouseOver but then it does not allow you to type the letter of a name for quick searching if you have a very long list. Any advice?
THanks.

Comment: What is `optionsSelect`?

Comment: ActiveX? Maybe not the best idea, because IE does (or at least should, not sure) block it by default, and I believe users who know `WScript.Shell` will also block it if asked...

Answer (score 0):

Write your code into `$(document).ready();` function.

1. include jquery-1.9.0 framework.
2. Try below code.

   ```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       alert("open the dropdownbox automatically onload");
       optionsSelect.focus();
       // Other statements
   });
   </script>
   // The rest of your code.
   ```